# Python Dictionary gradebook, how to print pretty and edit

Tags: python-3.x

1. Write a program that lists all the students and their grades in the dictionary. Do not just put the whole dictionary object or list object into the print function (i.e. print(grade_book)). You must forma your output.

   Here's the sample run of your program:

   ```
   Student ID  Grades
   203942      88, 78, 83
   236732      90, 78
   9874        78
   29746       79, 90 
   75893       82, 80 
   352418      77, 88, 84
   13563       90, 89, 92
   ```

My current code looks like this

```
grade_book = {   203942:  '88,78,83',
                236732:  '90,78',
                 9874:     '78',
                 29746:   'emphasized text79,90',
                 75893:    '82,80',
                 352418:  '77,88,84',
                 13563:   '90,89,92' }
print("Student ID, Grades")
for k,v in grade_book.items():
    print(k,v)
```

I can't seem to get it to print pretty and I will need to

```
Select 1 to display grades
Select 2 to add new student grade
Select 3 to quit
Selection: 2
```

Comment: You don't seem to try. Please give a [mre].

Comment: I am brand new to python so I'm sorry but idk what minimal reproducible example is?

Comment: Well if you click the link, there's a whole page explaining it.

Comment: I think I get it, if you copy my code above it outputs the information i need bu not in the format I need it?

Comment: print "{:<8} {:<15} {:<10}".format('Key','Label','Number')
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    label, num = v
    print "{:<8} {:<15} {:<10}".format(k, label, num)                                 I tried using this code i found on here but it says AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: all I'm asking is if there is somewhere i should be looking or a term to give me a pointer, I dont want anyone to do it for me like most of the things on here, I just want a direction so I can learn it

Comment: That's a better [mre], but you need more up-to-date learning materials; `dict.iteritems` [doesn't exist in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists). Why not try combining that string formatting with the working for loop in your post?

Comment: See I didn't know that, my professor is garbage and puts the assignment online with no material to read, it doesn't reference any chapter so it all all learn it yourself and give him the results. Sorry if it seemed like I only wanted the answer but I just don't know where to even start since I've tried researching the only commands and built-ins I know.

Comment: and when i remove iteritems to just items it gives me the error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2), i think this is b/c some of the grades are 1 and other are up to 3??

Comment: So there's your next error to Google and problem to debug. Repeat until it works. Welcome to programming!

Comment: Finally got it! idk why but it just clicked and i realized I didn't provide the key, i was trying to select both id and grades as values.

Comment: d = ({          203942:  '88, 78, 83',
                236732:  '90, 78',
                 9874:     '78',
                 29746:   '79, 90',
                 75893:    '82, 80',
                 352418:  '77, 88, 84',
                 13563:   '90, 89, 92' })

print("{:<20} {:<10}".format('Student ID','Grade'))
for [key, value] in d.items():
    student_id = key
    grade = value
    print("{:<20} {:<10}".format(student_id, grade))